# allow $HOME env var in execstart in systemctl.service file

Tags: systemd, systemctl

I want to do something like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=ROT13 demo service
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=1

[Service]
Type=simple
User=oleg
ExecStart=$HOME/.local/bin/cprev-agent   # user the home env var

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

is there a way to use a $HOME env var like I did there or does it need to be hardcoded?

Comment: Try ~/.local/cprev-agent, should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Later versions of systemd may have changed this, but in 237 or so you are not allowed `$` or `%` in the program, which also has to be an absolute path. You can get round this by, for example,

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash -c 'exec $HOME/.local/bin/cprev-agent'
```

Here the `$HOME` is expanded by the shell. systemd only expands such variables if they are a single word. You can use `${HOME}` to always have systemd replace it.

Comment: that's a good trick, nice one